# POLORVM-REGINA-OMNIVM-NOSTRA

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Please help me to solve this interesting puzzle. Someone asked me this before, but I can't find the answer.

> POLORVM-REGINA-OMNIVM-NOSTRA
>
> `skqjet`
>
> STELLA-MATVTINA-ORBIS-DOMINA

Answer (score 2):

A guess...

> The text is latin, and in fact the lyrics of a song written by:
> **Llibre vermell de Montserrat**
>
> The text translates to: Morning star (that) orbits lady
> Venus is refered to as the morning star, and it is seen on (lady) earth, as it moves from the eastern sky in the morning to the western sky in the early evening (thus the orbiting)
>
> **Venus**